# Laravel + AngularJS platform, loading issue on the website when it is online

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, loading, php-7

I have a website which is built by using Laravel + Angular.js, the website works completely fine offline on localhost(WAMP), but when I upload it online on google cloud platform VMs and set up everything properly, it does not load and shows the following error [Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WdIEW.png)

Comment: Looks like you're trying to use replace on an undefined variable, as well as loop through an undefined or null object. Usually happens when trying to fetch data from a third party that either doesnt exist or you dont have access to.

Comment: @derek it works fine completely offline, does not throw up any errors then, why mess up online then?

Comment: Theres so many answers to that question. CORs being the biggest IMHO

Comment: Can I put the angular.js file at the top to load so that it loads first and then everything else gets executed? or is it meant to be at the bottom only? can this help?

Comment: That probably wont help if CORs is your culprit

Comment: what is CORs? thanks for helping out till now

Comment: Also can I connect with you on some other platform through which I can explain you the issue more properly? @derek

Comment: Sure, what platform do you suggest? I have slack

Comment: @derek we could connect on Facebook, Twitter, Linkedin, or maybe messaging on stack if it exists(sorry I am a new guy here)?

Comment: Yeah we could chat on stack but I dont think you have that privilege yet. Shoot me your Facebook in a privnote or something

Comment: Got it thanks will connect